# Unable to connect yum repo

Tags: linux, centos, git

When I am running yum install getting following error.

```
root@datanode# yum list

CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config
file:///etc/yum.conf

 root@datanode# rpm -ev yum 

        error: Failed dependencies:
        yum >= 3.0 is needed by (installed) yum-fastestmirror-1.1.16-21.el5.centos.noarch
        yum >= 3.2.18 is needed by (installed) yum-security-1.1.16-21.el5.centos.noarch
        yum >= 3.2.22 is needed by (installed) yum-updatesd-0.9-6.el5_10.noarch


root@datanode# cd /etc/yum.repos.d 

root@datanode:/etc/yum.repos.d# ll

total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1926 Oct  7  2013 CentOS-Base.repo

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  636 Oct  7  2013 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  626 Oct  7  2013 CentOS-Media.repo

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7574 Oct  7  2013 CentOS-Vault.repo


root@datanode12.h2.dev.bigdata.sv2.247-inc.net:/etc/yum.repos.d# cat
/etc/yum.conf.FCS


[main] proxy=http://cache.backside.sv2.tellme.com:3128/

cachedir=/var/cache/yum keepcache=0 debuglevel=2

logfile=/var/log/yum.log distroverpkg=redhat-release tolerant=1

exactarch=1 obsoletes=1 gpgcheck=1 plugins=1

bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug

# Note: yum-RHN-plugin doesn't honor this. metadata_expire=1h

installonly_limit = 5

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo

# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your yum is broken...

`CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf` - Can you check your config file is actually at `/etc/yum.conf` and its contents is valid.

You could try and re-install from [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/31340516/dir/centos_6/com/yum-3.2.29-69.el6.centos.noarch.rpm.html). You may need to find your own deps.